# Page stall when passing data

Tags: django

I am trying to pass some data between pages, but it's not working. Any tips? I click submit and it takes me to a blank page. If I refresh then it shows my base template styles, but no data is passed.

index.html

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Vote{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<h1>Welcome</h1>

<form action="/polls/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<p><label for="pin">Enter group pin:</label>
    <input id="pin" type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4" />
  <input type="submit" value="View Polls" /></p>
</form>

    <a href="admin/">Moderator login</a>

</p>

{% endblock %}
```

polls/index.html

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Recent Polls{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{{ pin }}

{% endblock %}
```

polls/urls.py

```
url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            model=Poll,
            template_name='polls/index.html')),
```

Comment: Paste the code for the views.

Comment: I don't have any related views

Comment: What? How can you serve it? Urls.py? Are you following the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a view to handle the form submision. The view that works, is listing all your Polls. I recommend you to read the tutorial:

Basic views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/
Form submission: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/

Basically, your form will send the data to another URL that will handle the processing of your data.

You must specify it in the `action` attribute:

```
<form action="/polls/create-poll" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<input type='text' name='poll-name' />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

and in your views:

```
def create_poll(request):
    poll_name = request.POST.get('poll-name')
    poll = Poll.objects.create(name=poll_name)
    return HttpResponse("Poll created")
```

I don't want to sound rude. But you should start with some HTTP and HTML tutorial. A good web programmer is the one that knows the basic stuff in detail. HTTP is a great protocol, try to learn it all the way through.

Comment: Thank you, I will look this over. And yes, some basic HTTP would do me good.

Comment: I've got some experience. The best programmers, are those who have a pretty deep understanding of the basic stuff. HTTP, DNS, Network programming. Take some time in the week to read about it, just 2hr per week will make you a rock-star in a couple of years. Good luck!